# Given an odd integer $a$ , establish that $a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1$ is divisible by $12$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an odd integer $a$ , establish that $a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1$ is divisible by $12$?

So far I have:

$a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1$

$=a^2+a^2+4a+4+a^2+8a+16+1 $

$=3a^2+12a+21$

$=3(a^2+4a+7) $

where do I go from here.. the solution I have is divisible by $3$ not $12$...

Comment: Use that $a$ is odd to see divisibility by $4$.

Comment: how should I go about rewritting a?

Comment: $a = 2k+1$ is the standard way.

Comment: all odd integers are always written like that?

Comment: Sometimes one writes $2k-1$, occasionally, that is more convenient.

Comment: ok would k+1 or k-1 also be odd? why do you need the 2 coefficient in front of the k?

Comment: Take $k = 3$. Is $k+1$ or $k-1$ odd?

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is odd, then $a = 2b+1$ for some integer $b$.

Then $a^2 + 4a + 7 = 4b^2 + 4b + 1 + 8b + 4 + 7 = 4(b^2 + 3b  + 3)$, which is evenly divisible by $4$.

Combine this with the divisibility by $3$ that you already have, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Write $a = 2t+1$. Then $a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1=12 (t^2+3 t+3)$.

It may be simpler to write $b=a+2$. Then $a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1=(b-2)^2+b^2+(b+2)^2+1=3b^2+9$. Now $a$ odd implies $b$ odd, and so write $b=2u+1$. Then $3b^2+9=12 (u^2+u+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:***

If $a$ is odd then by the Division algorithm $a = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2+(a+2)^2+(a+4)^2+1=3a^2+12a+21\equiv3(a^2-1)\pmod{12}$$

Now, if $a$ is odd $a\pm1$ are even $\implies a^2-1$ will be divisible by $4$

In fact, $\displaystyle(2b+1)^2=4b^2+4b+1=8\frac{b(b+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod8$